# Merge Sort not working correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, merge

```
void mergeSubArr(int arr[], int lb, int mid, int ub){
    int temp[size], i = lb, j = mid, k = 0;
    while(i<mid && j<=ub){
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
            temp[k] = arr[i++];
        else
            temp[k] = arr[j++];
        k++;
    }
    while(i<mid)
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    while(j<=ub)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];

    for(k=0;k<size;k++)
        arr[k] = temp[k];

}

void mergeArr(int num[], int lb, int ub){
    int mid;
    if((ub-lb)>1){
        mid = (lb+ub)/2;
        mergeArr(num, lb, mid);
        mergeArr(num, mid+1, ub);
        mergeSubArr(num, lb, mid+1, ub);
    }
}
```

when calling the function mergeArr the output is outputting some other elements which are not initially present in the array? I think there is something wrong with the mergeSubArr function please help me out here in finding a solution.

Comment: How do you call the function? What input do you give it? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, together with the input and expected and actual output? Finally, have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger, line by line, to try and figure it out yourself?

Comment: please provide full code and sample input output

Comment: `for(k=0;k<size;k++)
        arr[k] = temp[k];` is wrong. `arr[ lb .. ub ]`, not `arr[ 0 .. size ]`

Comment: Your algorithm would be clearer if yu used the same kind of range (either inclusive or exclusive upper bound) for both ranges.

Comment: Do you know how to debug? If not, isn't it time to learn. You can't continue without that skill.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's way too late.  Trying to implement a merge sort, (or any sort), without the requisite debugging skills is just pointless and will just generate annoying posts to SO.  OTOH, it could be that the OP is just lazy and wants to outsource the difficult phases of development to SO contributors without any payment.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two things wrong with your algorithm:

You fill the array `temp` from index 0 on. Later, you need to copy it to `arr`, but starting at the lower bound. You also shouldn't copy `size` elements, because you can't be sure that the original array even has `size` elements. (Thanks, BLUEPIXY, for spotting this one.) You should probably also make sure that `size` is big enough to hold all elements.

Your upper bound is inclusive. That means that `if (ub - lb > 1)` catches the case where there are more than two elements. You still have to treat the case where there are two elements, which may be in the wrong order, either by making the above condition `ub - lb > 0` or by having an else clause where you swap the elements if they are in the wrong order.

So make these changes:

```
int temp[size], i = lb, j = mid, k = lb;
```

Start the temp array from the lower bound.

```
for(k = lb; k <= ub; k++)
    arr[k] = temp[k];
```

Copy only the subarray in question.

```
if (ub - lb > 0) ...
```

Catch the case where there are two elements, too.

On a personal note, I find the mergesort algorithm much easier when it passes subarrays via pointer arithmetic and length. It forgoes much fiddling with offsets.

Answer (score 0):

All are okk. Instead  `if((ub-lb)>1)` Just replace

```
if((ub-lb)>0)
```

OR

```
if(ub > lb)
```